# Recommended File Extension for rails view pages(2.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-extension

Which is the Recommended File Extension for rails view pages(2.3.2)

```
1.RHTML
2.html.erb
```

any significance in this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard naming:

```
template_name.mime_type.erb
```

Significance:

The controller will look for appropriately named template file when responding to different request formats:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # Looks for show.html.erb
      format.xml # this will look for show.xml.erb
      # OR you can always use render :xml facility
      # format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
end
```

Link for API Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods.html

Comment: ie if it is html then name.html.erb

Comment: They will essentially do the same thing, the naming is for better organization. For example, your layout files are still named `application.rhtml` or `users.rhtml`

Comment: rails will use the plain .erb file if it can't find mime_type.erb

Answer (score 0):

afaik, .rhtml has long been deprecated.